# iphone; Doing stuff only once the view appears..ViewWillAppear?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

Hi there
I ran into some confusion related to this; i would like to perform some actions only once the view is  appeared, probably showing an activity indicator while the data is being collected.
I have written my code in viewWillAppear, but it seems to be firing before the view appears on the screen.
I have double checked this with some NSLog statements, and i added a sleep of 2 seconds in viewWillAppear, the NSLog statements get fired, and the view appears only after 2 seconds delay - i was expected, the 2 second delay is executed once the view comes onto the screen?

Am i doing something wrong?
I even tried viewDidAppear, same thing. Any suggestions?

Thanks

edit: I would like to give a clear scenario of what i am doing

```
1. i have a parent view, which has a scroll view - and a subview
2. In the parent view, i create multiple instances of the subview and add them to the scrollview, creating scrollable views, which work.
3. Each view is passed an argument and depending on the argument the view contents change - works as expected.
4. I would like to show the subview and once its on the screen, do some internet opearations while i show an activity indicator, for this i need to use viewDidApper.
5. I am manually firing the subview's viewDidAppear from the parent view, once i have created its instance
```

The problem here is, the view is appearing only once all the operations are complete.

How can i sort this?

Answer (score 5):

`viewWillAppear` is supposed to fire BEFORE the view appears, hence the word **Will** in the name. You might be interested in `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Hi Abizem, as i have mentioned in my question, i have tried both - the same result!

Comment: -(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
 [activityIndicator startAnimating]; 
 [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
 [activityIndicator stopAnimating]; 
 
}
That's my code for testing, the view appears only after finishing everything, i even tried viewDidAppear:animated after the sleep as well

Answer (score 1):

I guess i figured it out - 
Rather than performing operations on viewDidAppear, i used performSelector, something like this

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self performSelector:@selector(loadXML:) withObject: self afterDelay:0];

}
```

Thanks guys!